# How do i get kafka to delete logs based on retention period provided

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka cluster or 3 brokers running on AWS EC2 instances. However the disk spaces on these machines quickly run out because of logs being generated by Kafka, and once the machines runs out of disk space, Kafka stops running. I have the following for cleanup policies in my `server.properties` file

```
log.retention.hours=24
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
```

The `log.retention.hours` was initially set to `168` as usual, but i thought maybe that was a long enough time for the disk to get full as I am running this on t2.small machines with 30GiB of disk storage, so i reduced this the retention hours to 24 and yet the disk still gets full.

I ran a `describe` on the topics to see if there is a larger retention policy on the topics, i thought maybe that was overwriting the `server.properties` file but the topic retention period is 1000ms as shown below after running `kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic create-user --describe`

[image]

Also in my `server.properties` file, my directory setting is `log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs` and i can see it's created some log files in that directory, however I am also see some logfiles in the directory kafka is installed in (~/kafka-dir) and there `logs` direcotory which grows. I have to log onto the machine to delete every single file from this directory (~/kafka-dir/logs) ever couple days before the disk runs out of space and this is getting very inconvenient.

How do i get kafka to delete the logs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't store data in `/tmp` if you plan on keeping that data.
2. Only *closed segments* are deleted. Seems you still have segment sizes set at 1GB
3. Check the broker logs to ensure the `LogCleaner` is actually running.